# Accessing element ID of linked SVG with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, inkscape

When trying to access inkscape svg elements with D3, nothing changes. No errors.

The SVG appears fine on my HTML

I already checked the ID in inkscape, and nesting `.select()`. Already made `svg` a global variable. I'm not getting any errors so I have no idea how this is slipping through the cracks.

```
<div id="CryoSVG">
   <script> svg = d3.xml('/Data/CryoConcept.svg').then(data => { document.body.append(data.documentElement);})</script>
   <script> d3.select("svg").select("V6").style("fill","blue");</script>
</div>
```

In practice I want D3 to read a file and change the color to red or green depending on value inside the txt. I am using blue just to illustrate.

I've tried looking into the Elements when inspecting the HTML in browser and using the id generated by D3 for the SVG (`id="svg8"`). Regardless of how I try to select the SVG, Nothing changes, No errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two scripts. Let's name them script 1...

```
<script> 
svg = d3.xml('/Data/CryoConcept.svg').then(data => { document.body.append(data.documentElement);})
</script>
```

... and script 2:

```
<script> 
d3.select("svg").select("V6").style("fill","blue");
</script>
```

You may think that, since script 1 comes before script 2, it is executed first and the element will be there for D3 to select. But here comes the problem: `d3.xml` return a promise. That is, it is **asynchronous**.

Therefore, script 2 will run **before** script 1 downloading the SVG and appending it.

Solution: use just one script, and move everything that depends on the appended SVG to inside the `then` method:

```
<script> 
svg = d3.xml('/Data/CryoConcept.svg').then(data => {
    document.body.append(data.documentElement);
    d3.select("svg").select("V6").style("fill","blue");
})
</script>
```